# Load/test previously trained and saved neural network Python

Tags: python, neural-network

I define my neural network

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # make sure input tensor is flattened
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
        
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc4(x), dim=1)
        
        return x

model = Classifier()
```

I train the neural network

I save the trained neural net:

```
checkpoint = {'input_size': 784,
              'output_size': 10,
              'hidden_layers': [256, 128, 64],
              'state_dict': model.state_dict()}

torch.save(checkpoint, 'checkpoint.pth')
state_dict = torch.load('checkpoint.pth')
```

when I try to load the saved neural network, I get an error

```
def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    # I believe the error is in the line directly below
    model_b = model(checkpoint['input_size'], checkpoint['output_size'], checkpoint['hidden_layers'])
    model_b.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    return model_b

model_b = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: show full error message - it should shows in which line exactly is problem. Maybe normal `nn.Model` has function `forward()` which gets 4 arguments and it used it in some places but you replaced it with `forward()` which gets only 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing up a few points:

- Your class `__init__` function takes no argument, your neural network has fixed parameters, so you can't use the other keys of your dict object to create a model that has the same parameters.
- A nn.Module function has a method called `__call__` that redirects to `forward` method. This function is run whenever you run `Object(something)` where something will be the function parameters. In `load_checkpoint`, you ran `model_b = model(checkpoint['input_size'], checkpoint['output_size'], checkpoint['hidden_layers'])`. You tried to do a forward pass using some elements from your dictionary. hence the error (the 4 parameters are `model`, `checkpoint['input_size']`, `checkpoint['output_size']`, `checkpoint['hidden_layers']`).

To fix the problem of loading the model, simply remove this line `model_b = model(checkpoint['input_size'], checkpoint['output_size'], checkpoint['hidden_layers'])` and I think it should work.

If you wish to create a model using the checkpoint input_size, output_size and hidden layers, you should use these parameters on the constructor:
`model = Classifier(checkpoint['input_size'], checkpoint['output_size'], checkpoint['hidden_layers'])`. Your code will need a few changes in order for this to work.